# Woocommerce Address1 and Address2 display on one line

Tags: woocommerce

I've searched for hours, tested a lot of things (editing files with no visible result), but i can't seem to find the solution so i humbly present my case for this community :-)

I'm using Woocommerce and set the address2 field required and renamed it so i can use it as a field for the house number. So far so good.

The problem i have is i want to display this on 1 line and not on 2 lines like the image below. This is the case on several pages, but mainly the one in the example is the most important one. Does anyone have any clue in what .php file or template this is hidden?

Thanks so much!

[image: Example]

Comment: tested a lot of things? please add in question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address` filter hook that allows you to change the billing address format. try the below code.

```
function change_order_formatted_billing_address( $address, $WC_Order ) {
    
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if( $current_screen == 'shop_order' && isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ){

        $address = array(
            'first_name'    => $WC_Order->billing_first_name,
            'last_name'     => $WC_Order->billing_last_name,
            'vat'           => $WC_Order->billing_vat,
            'company'       => $WC_Order->billing_company,
            'address_1'     => $WC_Order->billing_address_1.' '.$WC_Order->billing_address_2,
            'city'          => $WC_Order->billing_city,
            'state'         => $WC_Order->billing_state,
            'postcode'      => $WC_Order->billing_postcode,
            'country'       => $WC_Order->billing_country
        );
     }
    
    return $address;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address' , 'change_order_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: first of all thank you so much for taking the time and effort to help me!

I am assuming that i have to place the code in the functions.php of the template ( i have a main and child theme) but i don't see any change after adding it to any one of them. Maybe i'm doing it wrong or have to add it in another file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: i got it working! I changed it to *    if(  isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ){* and now it works

Comment: Also commented out $current_screen = get_current_screen();

Comment: Thank you Bhautik, please send me your paypal (to ray@sabee.nl) so i can buy you a coffee or 2 for your help. I think i checked and upvoted the answer. Thanks again!